# $I_d + u$ is invertible for u a Lipschitz function

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions, banach-algebras

Hoping you can help me out!

**Theorem.** Let $u \in Lip^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$, such that $||u||\leq \frac{1}{2}$ where $||u||= \text{ess} \sup |Du(x)|$, then $I_d+ u$ is invertible. Also, we have 
$$ (I_d+u)^{-1}=I_d+v \quad \text{ for some } v \in Lip^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n) $$ and $||v||\leq C ||u||$ where $C$ does not depend on u.

In the book is says that it follows immediately from the fact that $u$ is a contraction (this is clear, since $u$ is Lipschitz).
The question is then, how can it be proved that way?

What I did was to prove it using Banach Algebras, since the ball $\{ x+I: ||x||< 1\}$ is a subset of $A^{\times}$, where $A^{\times}$ is the set of all invertible elements of A, in this case $A=Lip^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$, but that only proves the invertible part, it isn't clear (at least to me) how the remaining follows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\|(I+u)-I\|=\|u\|<1\Rightarrow (I+u)^{-1}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^nu^n=I+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^nu^n$

Set $v=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^nu^n$ and note that

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^nu^n=u\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^nu^{n-1}$ and

$\|\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^nu^{n-1}\|\le 2$

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I tried, but the only thing that caused me discomfort is that theorems use $I_d-u$, and here I have $I_d+u$, so there's no such a big deal for a sign?   Also what's the importance of having the last bound of 2? Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Yes, the sign change is no problem. See my edit. The $2$ itself is not important. It just shows that there is a $C$, and $2$ is one that works.

Comment: hehe I see it now! finally where did you use that $u$ is a contraction? Thanks!

Comment: You use when you prove that $v$ is Lipschitz

Comment: Well, maybe I'm confused, but that theorem only applies to bounded and lineal operators, right? In that case $I_d + u$ is not lineal, it is affine.

Comment: Which theorem are you referring to? The expansion is valid in $any$ Banach space. That is, if $e$ is the unit in the Banach space $X$, and if $\|u\|<1$ then $(u-e)^{-1}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}u^n$

Comment: Really? Haven't found it yet, it is usually refer to $B(X)$ or for a Banach Alegebra, but in general for an operator $T$ in a Banach space I cannot recall one, do you have any reference?

Comment: [Here](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/olver/teaching/NCA/15.pdf) is a good reference. Look in the section on Neumann series

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I hahaha so the natural question is which one was first proved since all them are the same.

Comment: You mean the pdf? Yeah, it's kind of corrupted. But the proof is readable, no?

Comment: Oh no! I mean the theorems, in every FA book it is the same argument the only thing that changes is the space:B(X), Banach Algebra or a simple Banach Space.

Comment: Well, that's not surprising since $B(X),\mathbb R^n, L^p(X)$ etc are special cases of Banach spaces!

Comment: Oh well, for sure, though sometimes I get confused whenever the use the notation $\rho(T)$ instead of $||T||$, where the first is the spectral radius and the second simple operator norm.

Comment: They are intimately related right? In fact the matrix $2$ norm is equal to the spectral radius if the matrix is Hermitian. The spectral radius is of course bounded by any norm and for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a norm $\|\cdot\|$ such that  $\|A\|<\rho(A)+\epsilon. $